# How to Change Python Auto Completion to Venv Directory in Vim YCM

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

I have `venv` directory in my project (python3) which contains `activate`,`pip` and `python` files. I made it by:

```
python3 -m vevn venv
```

Normally it works fine, but it works with `/usr/bin/python` instead of `my_project/venv/bin/python`.

How can I change Vim YCM config to consider this directory as my main **Python interpreter** and **auto completion**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `venv` of current project, add this line in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:ycm_python_binary_path='./venv/bin/python'
```